# Eliminate small measurement error

Tags: noise

I have a 3D-printer z-axis noisy signal. What I am trying to achieve is to detect each printed layer according to the z-value (e.g. z = -53.5 -> 1st layer, z = -52.5 -> 2nd layer ...). 
However, due to the small measurement inaccuracies (marked in red), I'm having a hard time differentiating layers from each other.
Ideal would be replacing all errors by its previous value (e.g. all errors above or below 1st layer = -53.5 -> set them back to the 1st layer value) 
How can I approach this issue using DSP techniques?

[image]

Comment: what you describe is really pretty much a description of an algorithm, so I'd say you already have your DSP solution?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed. I'm looking for an algorithm. I have a solution that works more or less fine but not a DSP one

Comment: it is! It processes a digital signal –> it's DSP. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for your answer. Well, it turns out that my solution as expected. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: Don't understand?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry, typo. it turns out that my solution doesn't work as expected. How would you solve the problem?

Comment: by looking at how it doesn't work as expected and fixing that. Your solution is sound in principle.